# How to get the ajax region id using richfaces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have an application that is being migrated to richfaces from ajax4jsf. As known, ajaxcontext api has been removed and provided with extendedpartialviewcontext. But I am not able to get suitable replacement for below method. ideas ?

```
ajaxContext.getSubmittedRegionClientId
```

Comment: It would be better to say what are you trying to do, the method is gone, the process in which it was used has changed as well.

Comment: I need to find the client id of the ajax region . I tried to do using the extendedpartialviewcontext api, but not able to get the id. Pls help.

Comment: When you set `execute="@region"` (or leave it empty) the wrapping region is processed but as far as I can see the processing never deals with the id. If you need to find it you'll have to go through the tree yourself.

Comment: ok..the code in JSF 1.2 is as below. I am not able to figure out the way to get the submitted region id as below..   Are there any APIs in jsf 2/richfaces?                                                                             {AjaxContext ajaxContext = AjaxContext.getCurrentInstance(ctx);
            if (ajaxContext.isAjaxRequest(ctx)){               
             final String submittedRegion = ajaxContext.getSubmittedRegionClientId();}

Comment: The code doesn't do anything. You shouldn't be working with these internal processes unless you have a good reason to. Check where the id is used and if you actually need it.

Comment: What specific version of richfaces are you using?